# Looking to provision a file in a wiki library. URL invalid?

Tags: wiki

Any idea what the Url format should be for any site with a SitePages library?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MOWikiHomePage" List="119" Url="/SitePages">
    <File Path="MOWikiHomePage\Sample.txt" Url="Sample.txt" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE"/>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

The URL '/SitePages' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the "/" because Module can figure out the right path for you depending on the scope of the FEATURE.